# How to send SMS to more than one recipient with one time user interaction on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios5, ios4

Does anybody know, If it's possible, and how to send SMS to more than one recipient with one time user interaction. Which means, Our application should send SMS to a list of numbers with static message body when the user press the send button one time on iPhone?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not possible as long as you don't use your own service to send SMS